# React Native MapBox Get Clicked Location

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, mapbox, openstreetmap

I successfully added @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps to my project.
Now I **don't** need user's current location but I just need to get the coordinates (lat & lng) of where ever the user clicks on the map. I've tried everything but nothing works!
my code:

```
import MapboxGL, {MapView, UserLocation} from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';

MapboxGL.setAccessToken(
    'MyAccessToken', );


export default class .... .... {

getLastLocation(location) {

        ToastMaker(location, 'short')

    }

render() {

        return (
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={{height: '100%',
                        width: '100%',
                        backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
                        <MapView style={{ flex: 1}}

                          //These Don't Work!
                        //onUserLocationUpdate={(property) => this.getLastLocation(property)}
                        //onLongPress={(property) => this.getLastLocation(property[0].coordinates)}
                        //onLongPress={(property) => this.getLastLocation(property.geometry) }
                        //onLongPress={(property) => ToastMaker(property.properties.screenPointY,'short') }
                       >
                            <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                                draggable={true}
                                id={'1'}
                                selected={true}
                                coordinate={this.state.coordinates}
                            />
                        </MapView>
                    </View>
                </View>
        )
    }

}
```

*** All I need is the coordinates of where the user selects on the map** 
 **Thanks ***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`MapView#onPress`](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/MapView.md#props) property.

```js
<MapView
  ... 
  onPress={(feature)=>console.log('Coords:', feature.geometry.coordinates)}
>
  ...
</MapView>
```

See [ShowPointAnnotation.js](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/8cae0a28f784759ee5a4432c175cb3726826c63c/example/src/examples/ShowPointAnnotation.js#L80-L84) for complete example

Edited: fixed variable error "feature" in the function

Comment: And people say firefighters are the real heroes while we have one right here on Stackoverflow :D

Comment: @mrgeek absolutely, mfazekas is main contributor of react native mapbox gl. it really useful